# Não consigo montar autoload com PSR-4 para múltiplas pastas e subpastas

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Estou tentando passar um projeto para *MVC* e então criei a seguinte estrutura:

```
pasta_projeto
-App
--Controllers
---Classes
--Models
---Classes
--views
---html
-vendor
--Controller
---Action.php
--init
---Bootrstrap.php
```

Estou criando o arquivo `composer.json` dentro da pasta do meu projeto com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "name" : "pasta/projeto",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3" 
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "alpha",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name" : "autor",
            "email" : "autor@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "[Nome da pasta em vendor]\\":"vendor/[Nome da Pasta em vendor]",
            "App\\": "App/"

        }
    },
    "config" : {
        "bin-dir" : "bin"
    }
    }
```

Executando o comando no `composer dump-autoload -o` (no terminal) para carregar o *autoload*, minhas classes quando criadas estão com o *namespace*:

```
namespace App\[Pasta da Classe];
namespace [Nome da pasta em vendor]\[Pasta da Classe]
```

Ao utiliza-las:

```
use App\[Pasta da Classe]\[Nome da classe];
use [Nome da pasta em vendor]\[Pasta da Classe];
```

O problema é que o *PHP* não acha as classes que estão na pasta *vendor*, somente as classes da pasta *App*

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'nomedapastaemvendor\init\Bootstrap' not found
> in C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\pasta_projeto\App\Init.php on line 8        
> [Tue Mar 20 12:46:38 2018] ::1:62311 [500]: / - Class
> 'nomedapastaemvendor\init\Bootstrap' not found in
> C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\pasta_projeto\App\Init.php on line 8
> ```

Comment: Você tem que usar `use \<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>`

Comment: Ops, falha minha no use eu coloquei o nome da classe que estou querendo usar, no caso da pasta vendor não funcionou